# How to run a code if user gets 401 status code in all endpoints in Nestjs

Tags: jwt, nestjs, refresh-token

I'm using JWT and a refresh token. Because JWT expires in a short time, I want to refresh the access token if the user gets a 401 status code on the protected routes and then force the user to run the endpoint again with the new JWT token that they got.

I know it is doable in the front-end, but I want to know if it is possible to handle this in Nestjs.

Comment: Im not sure I understood what you mean. but if you mean filling the req.header in nest.js that's strange because what are you going to do with that? sending to client then what.

Comment: @mhmmdamiwn 
I'm gonna show you the flow I want to happen: User logins -> Gets access token and refresh token -> Goes to protected route (success) -> Access token expires -> Goes to protected routes ( 401 status code ) -> call refresh token function automatically to get new access token -> Run the protected route again. Is it possible to do the last 2 steps in the backend?

Comment: Unless the refresh token is sent with every access request, which seems insecure to me, it won't be possible, because who knows how expired that access token is or what source it came from and if they even have the refresh token, right?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a [Nestjs middleware](https://docs.nestjs.com/middleware) that intercepts every request to a protected route and checks if the JWT token is expired or not. If the token is expired, the middleware can use the refresh token to get a new JWT token from the authentication server and set it in the response headers.

For example:

```
@Injectable()
export class JwtRefreshMiddleware implements NestMiddleware {
  constructor(private readonly authService: AuthService) {}

  async use(req: Request, res: Response, next: () => void) {
    const token = req.headers.authorization?.split(' ')[1];
    if (token) {
      try {
        const decodedToken = jwt.verify(token, process.env.JWT_SECRET);
        req.user = decodedToken;
        next();
      } catch (err) {
        if (err.name === 'TokenExpiredError') {
          try {
            const refreshToken = req.cookies?.refreshToken;
            const newToken = await this.authService.refreshToken(refreshToken);
            res.setHeader('Authorization', `Bearer ${newToken}`);
            next();
          } catch (err) {
            // handle error
          }
        } else {
          // handle error
        }
      }
    } else {
      // handle error
    }
  }
}
```